# scan long receipt bill for OCR in ionic/ cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic3, ocr

I am an Ionic and Cordova app developer, I found api **ocr.space** for recognizing text through images. But I wanted to scan long receipts which are generated by any mall or shopping center. How can I scan a long receipt and read its data through OCR? I have tried the **cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr** plugin. Can we do first click more than one images and combine it to one PDF and then scan it?

Comment: Did you get any solution for it? I am also looking for such a solution..

Comment: I Used cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr plugin , no payment or subscription required for it. accuracy is also good. for long receipt scan i was taking multiple image of long receipt bill and merging in one file (PDF etc) then using ocr method getting result,

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer